# Como Enviar Imagem pro banco de dados

Tags: postgresql, vba, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Alguem Tem uma ideia de Como faço pra enviar uma imagem pra um banco de dados postgree numa tabela que tem um campo Imagem do tipo "bytea" so que programando em visual basic?
ja tentei de diversas formas, mas nao consigo nem salvar ela no banco

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma solução :D

```
Dim conn As New Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection
        Dim cadastro As New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand


        conn.ConnectionString = "Seu banco de dados"
        conn.Open()


        cadastro.Connection = conn
        cadastro.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO Produtos (Nome,Descricao,Valor,Peso,Quantidade,Imagem) values (@Nome,@Descricao,@Valor,@Peso,@Quantidade,@Imagem)")


        cadastro.Parameters.Add("@Nome", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txbNomPro.Text
        cadastro.Parameters.Add("@Descricao", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txbDesPro.Text
        cadastro.Parameters.Add("@Valor", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txbVal.Text
        cadastro.Parameters.Add("@Peso", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txbPeso.Text
        cadastro.Parameters.Add("@Quantidade", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txbQua.Text
        Dim memstr As New MemoryStream
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(memstr, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
        cadastro.Parameters.Add("@Imagem", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bytea).Value = memstr.ToArray
        cadastro.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Cadastrado Realizado Com Sucesso", vbInformation, "ATENÇÃO")
        MessageBox.Show("image inserted")

        conn.Close()
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).